# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Run Configurations: Make not an option?

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration

This is probably a simple question, but I just upgraded from IntelliJ IDEA 15 to 2017.1, and in my previous Weblogic run configuration when I would add an artifact, the "Before Launch" actions Make and Build would be added by default, if not present. (I would remove Build as I have an external script that builds all modules of my project.)

However, in 2017.1, there doesn't seem to be an option for Make in the "Before Launch" actions. Has it been renamed to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action is called **Build** since 2016 version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought that might be the answer, but didn't want to assume, since there was another "Build" action in previous versions.